# make RadioGroup to check button on ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android

i managed to do that by adding "actionDownChecker" on every RadioButton.

```
private View.OnTouchListener actionDownChecker = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                mTabbar.check(view.getId());
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

public void add(int radioButtonResourceId, Class<? extends Fragment> contentClass) {
    mContent.put(radioButtonResourceId, new TabInfo(radioButtonResourceId, contentClass));
    //hack to check radio button on ACTION_DOWN, not UP!
    mTabbar.findViewById(radioButtonResourceId).setOnTouchListener(actionDownChecker);
}
```

Is there another more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way I would know how to do it, is to physically change the code in the Listener.  I'm not the smartest guy when it comes to developing for android, but the default constructor sets the boxes attached to RadioButtons to check on release.

Unless someone else knows something I don't, you either have to modify the listener class, or modify the entry after the listener has been evoked (by adding your actionDownCheker). Personally if it was me, i would just copy and paste your actionDownChecker, that way your listener class isn't messed up for your next project.

I'm sure there are some applications for it, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that. If someone presses down on the wrong button, they can just move off the button before it is released to cancel the press.